# kubernetes connect multiple storageClasses

Tags: kubernetes, storage

I have longhorn installed in my Kubernetes cluster for the local node storage. But I also have external storage mounted as seperate storageClass. So I have **2 storageClasses**. Is there a solution to use both of them at the safe time for a pvc, a bit like RAID0 uses to different harddrives, to use the storage of both of them?

Comment: What goal do you try to reach with it? What is your intention?

Comment: I want to use the storage from the pod and some remote storage as expansion for the storage of the pod

Answer (score 1):

No, you only should give one storageClass name in a PVC.  As far the k8s doc, Each StorageClass contains the fields provisioner, parameters, and reclaimPolicy, which are used when a PersistentVolume belonging to the class needs to be dynamically provisioned.

Also, StorageClasses are the foundation of dynamic provisioning, allowing cluster administrators to define abstractions for the underlying storage platform. Users simply refer to a StorageClass by name in the PersistentVolumeClaim (PVC) using the “storageClassName” parameter.